# Tableau : Create a Date Filter that Defaults to Yesterday's Date

Tags: filter, dashboard, tableau-api

I have a workbook view that I wish would reset by default to yesterday's date everytime someone would want to consult it.

My issue is that when I input a relative date into my filter the end user loses the choices they could have made with the dropdown list.

Basically I want the user to be able to choose between weekdays like this on my dashboard :
[Choosing between weekdays. Excuse the French](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iKgL.png)

My issue is once I put Yesterday as the default value for the filter, the end user only has this as a choice :

[Once I put the filter to auto update to yesterday, end users only have these choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLhxO.png)

I can join a dummy workbook if needed, I do not know if I made myself clear.

Comment: i will apreciate more information to help you if it is not soluted!!, maybe a printscreen...... regards...

Comment: [This is what I got](https://i.imgur.com/ZyfKDth.png) following the steps from [this thread](https://community.tableau.com/thread/194212). Hier means Yesterday, the rest are the days of the week. What I would want is the possibility to select several days, [like this](https://i.imgur.com/PDSULfU.png), while still having it default to Yesterday

Comment: You can find my workbook [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Bf0zGKxRdeUADLNwHVDIoa4F_6oO50cj), if it is any help

Comment: You may see this link .... I think Is what you need....I needed to down convert to tableau 10.1... but you won't have any problem opening it....https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sMhpOPMNA4lDhFvFg9BgTKlByVdEZGt4     when your users enters then it says filter on yesterday.... see blue part..... and you may change that to 1 week to 1 month... etc... I think is a good option.... also you can filter by year, month and day with actions on the dashboard filtering the information....

Comment: That's actually a creative solution ! Thanks a lot JWBG :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. Right-click and drag the date dimension to the filter shelf.
2. Select Relative dates > Yesterday.
3. From the filter shelf, right-click the date dimension and select Show Filter.

Or:

1. Create a calculated field by selecting Analysis > Create Calculated Field to create a calculated field.
2. In the Calculated Field dialog box that opens, enter a name for the field.
3. In the formula field, create a calculated field similar to the following:
   [Date Field]=today()-1
   where [Date Field] is the date field being used in the view. Click OK.
4. Drag the newly created calculated field from the Dimensions pane to the Filter shelf.
5. In the Filter dialog box that opens, select True, and then click OK.
6. From the filter shelf, right-click this new calculated field and select Show Filter.

**editied**
**By definition an IF statement IS boolean, so you just need to move the logic in front of the THEN, like this:**

```sql
    IF [Date Selection]=1 AND Date <= today() and Date >= dateadd('day', -6, today()) THEN [Date]
ELSEIF [Date Selection]=2 AND Date <= today() and Date >= dateadd('week', -4, today()) THEN [Date]
ELSEIF [Date Selection]=3 AND Date <= today() and Date >= dateadd('month', -2, today()) THEN [Date]
ELSEIF [Date Selection]=4 AND [Date] <= [End Date] and [Date] >= [Start Date] THEN [Date]
END
```

> Refernce: tableau.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am in the same situation than before. 

I can create the filter to default to yesterday, but then the end user will not have the same filter option as before.

Comment: so you want day yesterday and not the date yesterday. am I correct?

Comment: Basically I want yesterday (ie monday) do be shown by default, BUT I also want users viewing the dashboard to be able to select wednesday and friday for exemple (therefore "overwriting" the default value.) You can see my issue in the second image from my OP : When I put in relative dates or calculation, users cannot anymore have the weekdays view

Comment: understood , does this helps: https://community.tableau.com/thread/194212

Comment: That's actually perfect. Thanks a lot @DeshDeep Singh !

Comment: Sadly it appears that I am still losing some functionality from the basic filter, since the end user cannot select more than one day (ie monday and wednesday). I've looked it up a bit and apparently it is not possible to have the possibility to select multiple values out of a parameter.